Adobe Bridge adds metadata to JPG as a sidecar XMP instead of writing it on the JPG file
Using the latest Adobe Bridge 2024 (v.14.1.0) I have encountered an annoying bug recently. When I modify the metadata (such as tags, rating etc) of some JPEG files, instead of writing the changes on the JPEG file, it creates a sidecar XMP file, which is very annoying and may create problems when I transfer the file (upload to the cloud etc. or Flickr). It happens with some files (not with all of them) and I think the pattern I detected is that the files impacted are those recently edited with generative AI. Is there a way to solve this annoying bug?
Update: According to source 1, the issue is probably created by a conflict with Adobe Camera Raw 16.3.1. A user claims that manually downgrading to Adobe Camera Raw 16.0.0 solves the problem.
Related Links:

In Adobe Forums two users report exactly the same bug!
Google search
Adobe Bridge Bug Report
Question in Adobe Forum about using XMP with RAW files


Were the images edited in PS raw files that were saved as jpegs?

No. No RAW files. They started as JPG and finished as JPGs. It also happened to JPG downloaded from Adobe Firefly (as JPGs).

Apperantly the bug was caused by the new Adobe Camera Raw v16.3.1, which conflicts with AI-generated content. A temporary solution is to manually downgrade to Adobe Camera Raw v16.0 from here: https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-plug-in-installer.html in Adobe website. One needs to click the 14.5 link but change in the URL from 14x to 16x and from 14_5 to 16_0, and then restart the computer. It worked for me.
Update 2024-08-21:
Adobe are aware of this problem, see https://helpx.adobe.com/bridge/kb/xmp-file-jpeg.html . Their best suggestion so far is to downgrade Adobe Camera Raw to version 16.2. I hope Adobe Camera Raw next version will solve this issue.
Update 2024-10-14:
The issue was solved in ACR 17.0 and Adobe Bridge 15.0.
